# WSO2 ESB: multi-user install

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have User1 installed WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.
When User1 runs the server, there are user-specific files created (like `/repository/components/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`). 
So when User2 runs the same server it gets
 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)`.
How to run the server by User2?

P.S. I expected user-specific files to be created at home directory of each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with file permissions..If anyone wants to run the server, that person has an access for those folders to read write logs etc..
That permission is an OS level permission. Not at the product level permission

Comment: Thanks. I want to run the server _not_ by anyone, but _group_ of users. As I mentioned, if User1 starts server, user-specific files are created in product's directory (with user==User1, group==User1), so User2 can't read/write/execute it. How would I allow User2 to start the server?

Comment: I dont think controlling the access of staring server with different users can be done with product level. But you can restrict the access for different users based on role, etc..for different operations eg: login permission, resource access permission..

Comment: Thanks @Ratha. So one installed instance of ESB can be started only by one user (OS level), right?

Comment: No, i meant ,Restricting  the people to access server, is your internal organization policy/security system isn't it? Then at OS level we can define permissions.. then at product level, we have different level of access control/permission systems as i mentioned above. You can check the available permissions at user/roles configuration menu at management console